# Looking for a modern treatment of conics over arbitrary fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I'm looking for a modern treatment of conics over arbitrary fields (ie, viewed as algebraic curves of genus 0).

In particular, I'd like a reference for their connection with ternary quadratic forms, that they're irreducible if and only if the determinant of the corresponding quadratic form is nonzero...etc.

I'm sure this must exist somewhere, but I can't seem to find a complete reference for them.

Ideally this would appear as an appendix or a segment of a chapter of a more advanced book written in the modern language of schemes.

Comment: Are you looking to learn this material or to cite it?

Comment: @KReiser Mostly to cite it, but I guess partly also to learn it.